# how to let Jest test for "permission denied"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have the following test in jest:

```ts
describe('On any platform', (): void => {
      it('throws an error when trying to start with an invalid socket Path.', async(): Promise<void> => {
        const factory = new BaseHttpServerFactory(handler, httpOptions);
        expect((): void => {
          factory.startServer('/fake/path');
        }).toThrow()
      });
    });
```

which tries to start up a node http server with an invalid path for the socket file. As expected, this results in a "EACCESS: Permission denied '/fake/path'" error. However, this error is not being caught by Jest, and so the test fails with the message "The received function did not throw".

How can Jest test for these kind of expected errors?

I have checked for any more applicable methods to chain onto the expect method, but as far as I can tell, `toThrow()` is the only one to be able to test for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Node.js server.listen() function returns a server instance synchronously, but starts up the listening procedure asynchronously. So the above function call in fact didn't throw. The solution was to have the test itself set an error callback on the server so it could check the raised error like so

```
describe('On any platform', (): void => {
      it('throws an error when trying to start with an invalid socket Path.', async(): Promise<void> => {
        const factory = new BaseHttpServerFactory(handler, httpOptions);
        factory.startServer('/fake/path')
          .on('error', (error): void => {
            expect(error).toHaveProperty('code', 'EACCES');
          });
      });
    });
```